# How to go to a particular subdirectory and file in python from a given path

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to go to a subdirectory of the current working directory in Python to access a CSV file. However the normal OS based approach of simply spending name followed by / is not working. How can this be acheived

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import os

pwd = os.getcwd()
print(pwd)
df = pd.read_csv(pwd/scripts/list.csv)
```

Here scripts is a subdirectory in pwd and list.csv is the file within it

Comment: Your file name isn't quoted. That wouldn't work, even if there wasn't any slashes in there. Also, you don't need to get the cwd, simply use `.` to refer to it like this: `"./scripts/list.csv").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JoachimSauer said your path is not quoted. You can use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'{pwd}/scripts/list.csv')
```

However, you should use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module instead of creating a file path yourself:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

cwd = pathlib.Path.cwd()
df = pd.read_csv(cwd / 'scripts' / 'list.csv')
```